# Overriding Maximum Timeout in C# Transactions. Is it advisable?

Tags: c#, timeout, transactionscope, system.reflection

I have a set of DB statements (inserts, updates etc) inside a transaction that get executed in a for loop, like this.

```
using (Transaction)
{
  for (loop until x values)
  {
    Insert
    Update
  }
}
```

Then I have `complete() and dispose()` for `TransactionScope`.  It works fine for lesser number of 'x'.  But if x is significantly large, then the transaction times out as it's defaulted to 10 minutes (from machine.config)

My question: when we can guarantee there can be no deadlocks, is it good to increase the timeout in the code level for that TransactionScope?  I'm using the below code to override the default (from 10 minutes to 4 hours). It works fine, but is it advisable?

```
        public static class TransHelper
        {
            public static void OverrideMaximumTimeout(TimeSpan timeout)
            {
                var type = typeof(TransactionManager);
                var cachedMaxTimeout = type.GetField("_cachedMaxTimeout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
                cachedMaxTimeout.SetValue(null, true);

                var maximumTimeout = type.GetField("_maximumTimeout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
                maximumTimeout.SetValue(null, timeout);
            }
        }
```

I'm calling like,

```
TransHelper.OverrideMaximumTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(4));
```

Comment: Is it advisable?  That's a pretty loaded question.  It really depends on if you regularly expect your transactions to take longer than 10 minutes to complete on a normal basis or not.  Honestly if it's taking that long though, you might want to reconsider how much data is being pushed through in a  given transaction, and determine if there's any way to cut back on it.

Comment: @user2366842: there's nothing to cut though, but the frequency I expect is once or twice a month. That too for transaction time between 30 minutes to an hour

Comment: There are scenarios where this situation occurs.  That's why you're allowed to override and manipulate. The advisable section of this question is a whole other issue.

Take a look at how this is working, as well as how often this is going to run.  Is it a one time thing? Do you need to do the full data set in a single transaction?  Furthermore have you taken a look at optimizing how you're doing the inserts/updates, such as leveraging the SqlBulkCopy to do 1000's of updates/inserts rather than do each one individually?

Comment: @mikeswright49: thanks for your inputs.  It's going to be once or twice a month.  The transaction timeout I have given is to cover up the extreme as I don't think to expect to have between 30 minutes to an hour in a real time case.  Also the inserts and updates are specific to every 'x' element; so bulk insert / update is not an option here.

Comment: If that's the case, then you might be ok with the transaction. You might want to take a look at your tools being used (Is C# the best tool for this? Should you take a look at leveraging Event Queues? Sql Jobs?). If you're truly boxed in, then I have seen VERY limited use cases where what you're doing is correct, and it should be done this way.